# Ruby equivalent of find in unix

Tags: ruby, tree, rubygems, directory

Is there an equivalent for GNU find or PERL's File::Find in Ruby, maybe gems?
That is, transverse the entire tree.
Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Stdlib offers both [`Dir#glob`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob) and the [`Find`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html) module. Coupled with Enumerable methods and the plethora of file test methods, this gives you all you need to simply implement file find behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dir.glob

```
Dir.glob "**/*" do |file_path|
    #do somthing with file_path
end
```